# No output from jasmine-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine-node

I'm new to JavaScript, Node.js and jasmine. I'm trying to run a test from the book "The Node Craftsman Book", FilesizeWatcher. I've created the package.json file and run "npm install", thus installing jasmine-node locally to the project. When I run jasmine-node on the spec file I see only output from console.log but nothing from jasmine. I can see from console.log statements that calls to jasmine (e.g. expect(err).toBe("Path does not start with a slash");) are made, but there is no output.

Any idea of where i should start to find an error?

Comment: Please also post the relevant code of your tests. Also, try to run it with the `--captureExceptions` Flag.

Comment: Jasmine, [since version 2.0](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/node.html) has support for `node.js` by default, so you don't need `jasmine-node`.

Comment: I have a similar issue but the answer here isn't working for me.  Here is my question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/35641040/1735836

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know what code you are referring to. The problem is

```
watcher.on('grew', function(gain) { 
 expect(gain).toBe(5);
 done();
});
```

Replace with:

```
watcher.callbacks['grew'] = function(gain) { 
 expect(gain).toBe(5);
 done();
}
```

The core of the problem seems to be that the test is written to run on different code.  From a pure JS point of view, `watcher` object does not have the `on` "key" and therefore, by simply reading the code, I would not expect it to work.  I am new to Node too so, at first, I simply assumed that it would work.  I think the lesson there is: JS is JS and nothing node does with it changes that.  I found a much better introduction in a book called "Eloquent Javascript".  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and discovered that by adding the switch:

`--captureExceptions`

Mentioned by @Charminbear in the comments above, jasmine-node produced a list of errors in my scripts. Fixing these resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work after realising a few errors on my part.

Firstly, I still had `self.callbacks = {};` in my code. I removed this.
Secondly, I was still using `self.callbacks['error']('Path does not start with a slash');`. I changed it to `self.emit('error', 'Path does not start with a slash');`

Problem solved (for me).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, thanks @John Doherty's answer, I discovered my problem:

```
self.callbacks = {};
//...
FilesizeWatcher.prototype.on = function(eventType, callback) {
    this.callback[eventType] = callback;
};
```

It's a typo on `this.callback`, it should be `this.callbacks`:

```
FilesizeWatcher.prototype.on = function(eventType, callback) {
    this.callbacks[eventType] = callback;
};
```